# Vim function to copy a code function to clipboard

Tags: function, vim, block

I want to have keyboard shortcut in Vim to copy a whole function from a Powershell file to the Windows clipboard. Here is the command for it:

1) `va{Vok"*y` - visual mode, select {} block, visual line mode, go to selection top, include header line, yank to Windows clipboard.

But it would work only for functions without an inner {} block. Here is a valid workaround for it:

2) `va{a{a{a{a{a{a{Vok"*y` - the same as (1), but selecting {} block is done multiple times - would work for code blocks that have 7 inner {} braces.

But the thing is - the (1) command works fine when called from a vim function, but (2) misbehaves and selects wrong code block when called from a vim function:

```
function! CopyCodeBlockToClipboard ()
    let cursor_pos = getpos('.')
    execute "normal" 'va{a{a{a{a{a{a{Vok"*y'
    call setpos('.', cursor_pos)
endfunction

" Copy code block to clipboard
map <C-q> :call CopyCodeBlockToClipboard()<CR>
```

What am I doing wrong here in the CopyCodeBlockToClipboard? 
The (2) command works as expected when executed directly in vim.

UPDATE:

I've noticed that:

- if there are more a{ then the included blocks in the function
- then vim wouldn't execute V

Looks like vim handles errors differently here. Extra a{ produces some error and regular command execution just ignores it. But execution from withing a function via :normal fails and wouldn't call V (or probably any command that follows the error).

Any workaround for this?

Comment: From the looks of it you want to do this from any arbitrary position in the function. Is this correct?

Comment: True. Any position in a function that uses {} braces for code blocks and always uses one line for the function header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
function! CopyCodeBlockToClipboard() 
    let cursor_pos = getpos('.')
    let i = 1
    let done = 0
    while !done
        call setpos('.', cursor_pos)
        execute "normal" 'v' . i . 'aBVok"*y'
        if mode() =~ "^[vV]"
            let done = 1
        else
            let i = i + 1
        endif
    endwhile
    execute "normal \<ESC>"
    call setpos('.', cursor_pos)
endfunction
```

This preforms a execute command to select blocks until it fails to select a block larger block. (`[count]aB` selects `[count]` blocks) It seems when the selection fails we end up in visual mode. So we can use `mode()` to check this.

When this function exits you should be in normal mode and the cursor should be restored to where you started. And the function will be in the `*` register.

Answer (score 1):

This macro should come close to what you want to achieve:

```
?Function<CR>  jump to first Function before the cursor position
v              enter visual mode
/{<CR>         extend it to next {
%              extend it to the closing }
"*y            yank into the system clipboard
```

Comment: I know how to record this macro via q. But I don't know how to put it in a function. ':normal ?Function<>CR' apparently doesn't work. Also I can save such macro in bin form, but that wouldn't preserve the current cursor position.

Comment: Here is what I came up with. But it doesn't work and my vim knowledge is not enough to figure out what's wrong:

`function! CopyCodeBlockToClipboard()`
`let cursor_pos = getpos('.')`
`let @q = '?function\|filter<CR>v/{<CR>%"*y'`
`execute 'normal @q'`
`call setpos('.', cursor_pos)`
`endfunction`